# SQL Order Results Count by specific Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have a table with the following data:

```
Snack ID   |   Child    |  Fruit

1              Child A     Apple
2              Child B     Orange
3              Child A     Banana
4              Child A     Orange
5              Child C     Banana
6              Child A     Banana
7              Child C     Banana
8              Child A     Banana
```

And another table listing out the fruits available in each Child's hometown grocery:

```
Child ID   |   Child Name   |  Local Fruit 1  | Local Fruit 2 |  Local Fruit 3 

1              Child A         Apple            Mango            Orange
2              Child B         Orange           Banana           Cherry
3              Child C         Banana           Mango            Apple
```

I need to order the results, from highest to lowest, for the number of a specific fruit eaten for each child, but only if said fruit is one of their hometown fruits;

If the query is "Orange", I need the results to display as below:

```
Hometown Orange Eaters (Highest to Lowest)

Child   |   Number of Fruits eaten

Child A     1
Child B     1
```

if the query is "Mango":

```
Hometown Mango Eaters

Child   |   Number of Fruits eaten

Child A     0
Child C     0
```

For Bananas (Child A is not displayed, despite eating the most bananas, as this is not one of their hometown fruits):

```
Hometown Banana Eaters

Child   |   Number of Fruits eaten

Child C     1
Child B     0
```

The SQL command I am currently using is as follows:

```
select child, sum(fruit = '$fruit') `Number of fruits eaten`
from meals
group by child
order by `Number of fruits eaten` desc
```

However, this only displays results for those that have already eaten the fruit; e.g. for the banana example, only the below is displayed:

```
Hometown Banana Eaters

Child   |   Number of Fruits eaten

Child C     1
```

How can I adjust the current command so that all "hometown fruit" children are displayed, regardless of if they have eaten said fruit or not?

Comment: Is `meals` related to one of your tables?

Comment: Yes, the first table is the 'meals' table, thank you

Comment: Columns like `Local Fruit 1`, `Local Fruit 2`, ... are an anti-pattern. What if there are more than 3 local fruits? You should normalize your schema with a table that has a separate row for each `child ID + Local Fruit` combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
select child,
    (select count(*) from meals m where m.child = l.child and m.fruit = ?)  cnt
from listing l
where ? in (local_fruit_1, local_fruit_2, local_fruit_3)
order by cnt
```

The logic is to filter the `listing` table for rows where the concerned fruit can be found. Then, we use a correlated subquery to bring the count of fruits that were eaten.

The question marks represent the fruit whose analysis you want to bring.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a `join` and aggregation with filtering:

```
select s.child, sum(c.fruit = $fruit) as num_fruit
from snacks s join
     child c
     on c.child_id = s.child
where $fruit in (c.local1, c.local2, . . . )
group by s.child
order by num_fruit desc;
```